# PHP - Search Not Working

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I tried to make a search engine in order to search between 2 dates $dateFrom to $dateTo.

Here what i have tried.:

Index.php:

```
<?php
    require_once 'Connection.simple.php';
    $tutorialTitle = "Using Ajax to search a Record with PHP, MySQL and jQuery (Look and Feel by Bootstrap)";

    $conn = dbConnect();
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title><?php echo $tutorialTitle;?></title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
        <meta name="copyright" content="BEHSTANT SOFTWARE | Datasoft Engineering 2013"/>
        <meta name="author" content="Reedyseth"/>
        <meta name="email" content="ibarragan at behstant dot com"/>
        <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $tutorialTitle;?>" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel=stylesheet href="css/style01.css">
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="page-header ">

                <div class="panel panel-default">

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="mainContent">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="get">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="minimum date">employee_id</label>
                        <div class="input-group col-sm-9">
                            <input id="DateFrom" name="DateFrom" type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Type the name" />
                            <input id="DateTo" name="DateTo" type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Type the name" />
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btnSearch">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"> Search</span>
                                    </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                <!-- This table is where the data is display. -->
                    <table id="resultTable" class="table table-striped table-hover">

                        <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.btnSearch').click(function(){
                makeAjaxRequest();
            });

            $('form').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                makeAjaxRequest();
                return false;
            });

            function makeAjaxRequest() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'search.php',
                    type: 'get',
                    DateFrom: {DateFrom: $('input#DateFrom').val()},
                    DateTo: {DateTo: $('input#DateTo').val()},
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('table#resultTable tbody').html(response);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Search.php:

```
<?php

    require_once 'Connection.simple.php';
    $conn = dbConnect();
    $OK = true; 
   if (isset($_GET['DateFrom']) && isset($_GET['DateTo'])) {    
    $dateFrom = $_GET['DateFrom'];
    $dateTo = $_GET['DateTo'];


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE date >= '". $dateFrom ."' AND date <= '". $dateto ."' ";
    }
    if(empty($rows)) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td colspan='4'>There were not records</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    else {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row['emp_id']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['Date']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['day']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['time_in']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['time_out']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['worked']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['overtime']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['less_hours']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['transport_in']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['Transport_out']."</td>";


            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }

?>
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE date >= '". $dateFrom ."' AND date <= '". $dateto ."' ";
        // we have to tell the PDO that we are going to send values to the query
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        // Now we execute the query passing an array toe execute();
        $results = $stmt->execute(array($dateFrom, $dateTo));
        // Extract the values from $result
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $error = $stmt->errorInfo();
```

******I added that to make execute the query but still not working******

```
<?php
function dbConnect (){
    $conn = null;
    $host = 'localhost';
    $db =   'payroll';
    $user = 'root';
    $pwd =  '';
    try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $user, $pwd);
        //echo 'Connected succesfully.<br>';
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo '<p>Cannot connect to database !!</p>';
        echo '<p>'.$e.'</p>';
        exit;
    }
    return $conn;
 }

 ?>
```

******* This is my code for DBconnection*******
My database name is payroll and the table is attendance.

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you tell us specifically what you expect this code to do and what it actually does.

Comment: What error you getting ?

Comment: The code is used to get the attendance between the dates. I am expecting to have 2 textbox(input) from one date to another and when the query is executed the table gets all the columns in the database between that date

Comment: It shows **There were not records**

Comment: [Pic for the database](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ovonfxo6du6q686/ScreenShot.png?dl=0)

Comment: may i know from where you are getting $rows? You wrote a sql statement but you didn't executed it.

Comment: @Vinie And it's unclear, what mysql library does he use: mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @akki2401 Please, show dbConnect function

Comment: @user4035 I have added the dbConnect

Comment: @akki2401 Are you sure, that there is data in the database, matching your request? Try to `print "SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE date >= '". $dateFrom ."' AND date <= '". $dateto ."' ";` and execute the code in mysql directly.

Comment: @user4035 yes sir because when i run the query in phpmyadmin my the same format i am using in the html form it works perfectly

Comment: @akki2401 Can you dump your test database somewhere for me (http://pastebin.com/), so I could run your code on my system. It's almost impossible to consult without getting a quick feedback from the system.

Comment: @user4035 Here is it [DATABASE](http://pastebin.com/vEXeNk1Z)

Comment: @akki2401 Will look soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to name the parameters inside SQL code.
2. Please, use the correct case for the columns names. You spelled "less_hours", while in your database this column is called "Less_Hours". And this gave a notice: "Undefined index: less_hours".
3. I put the output code inside the 1-st `if`, otherwise `$rows` will always be undefined for the first time.

This code worked for me:

```
if (isset($_GET['DateFrom']) && isset($_GET['DateTo'])) {
    $dateFrom = $_GET['DateFrom'];
    $dateTo = $_GET['DateTo'];


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE 
            date >= :date_from AND date <= :date_to ";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    // Now we execute the query passing an array toe execute();
    $results = $stmt->execute(
                      array('date_from' => $dateFrom, 'date_to' => $dateTo));
    // Extract the values from $result
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(empty($rows)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td colspan='4'>There were not records</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    else {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row['emp_id']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Date']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Day']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Time_In']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Time_Out']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Worked']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Overtime']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Less_Hours']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Transport_In']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Transport_Out']."</td>";

            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir It is still not working. I have replaced all except:    **require_once 'Connection.simple.php';
    $conn = dbConnect();
    $OK = true;**

Comment: @akki2401 Try to hard-code the dates: $dateFrom = '2014-01-01', $dateTo = '2014-12-31'

Comment: here is what i have been trying: [hardcoded](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p1xecrllox2t8tn/search.php?dl=0) & [The one you gave me](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/as4g9do69lopm2v/AADADVYkauf5fLluSjEEhtiWa?dl=0)

Comment: @akki2401 What was the issue?

Comment: @akki2401 Remove the quotes around the parameters names in $sql: `SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE date >= :date_from AND date <= :date_to`. Not your variant `SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE date >= ':date_from' AND date <= ':date_to'`

Comment: The code is now this `$sql = SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE date >= ':date_from' AND date <= ':date_to' ;` it was `$sql = "SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE date >= :date_from AND date <= :date_to ";` and now i am getting error **syntax error, unexpected 'attendance' (T_STRING) in**. can you send me the html and php files you made by dropbox or something

Comment: @akki2401 Hi, I didn't mean to remove quotes around the string, just around the parameters. So the line should look exactly as in my answer: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE 
            date >= :date_from AND date <= :date_to ";`

Comment: @user4025 Thanks for that but the code is not working at all like when i press search btn it does nothing

Comment: @akki2401 No idea. It works for me. Try to debug yourself. This error seems very minor to me.

Comment: can you share the **whole** code through pastebin.com or dropbox.com for all the files you have been using.